# SQL select newst data in 2 table same primary key

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have two same table:
`A(id, ..., modified_date)`
and `B(id, ..., modified_date)`. I need to select the record with same id but `modified_date` larger.

How can I write the SQL? Please help.

Example:

Table A

```
id | user name | email         | modified date
------------------------------------------------
 1 | Anne      | ana@gmail.com | 2016/12/20
```

And table B

```
id | user name | email           | modified date
------------------------------------------------
 1 | Anne Jr,  | ana_j@gmail.com | 2017/01/20
```

With two record has same id, I need to get the record with `modified_date` larger. The example above, with `id = 1`, I need to select the record has `modified_date = 2017/01/20`

Comment: Provide sample data and expected output

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group+sql

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I am using Postgres.

Comment: Is it possible that table B contains more then one row for the same ID?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: no, it not possible. ID is unique

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the higher of those two values, then use `greatest()` with a join:

```
select ta.id, 
       greatest(ta.modifed_date, tb.modified_date)
from table_a ta
   join table_b tb on ta.id = tb.id;
```

If you want all columns from the row with the later date, you can use a `case` statement:

```
select ta.id, 
       case 
         when ta.modified_date > tb.modified_date then ta.email
         else tb.email
       end as email,
       case 
         when ta.modifed_date > tb.modified_date then ta.user_name
         else tb.user_name
       end as user_name, 
       greatest(ta.modified_date, tb.modified_date) as modified_date         
from table_a ta
   join table_b tb on ta.id = tb.id;
```

Comment: thanks very much, in the past I think case when statement can not work with other field like this :))

Answer (score 1):

You can do a `JOIN` and then `ORDER BY` `modified_date` column like

```
select t1.id,t1.modified_date
from table1 t1 join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
order by t1.modified_date desc;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need data from the B table, you can use :

```
SELECT    b.*
FROM      B b
WHERE     b.id = a.id
AND       b.modified_date > a.modified.date
```

Similarly, if you need data from the A table you can use :

```
SELECT    a.*
FROM      A a
WHERE     a.id = b.id
AND       a.modified_date > b.modified.date
```

In case there are multiple records which fit the criteria and you need only the one record which has the greatest modified date value then you can use :

```
SELECT    TOP 1 a.*
FROM      A a
WHERE     a.id = b.id
AND       a.modified_date > b.modified.date
ORDER BY  a.modified_date
```

OR

```
SELECT    TOP 1 b.*
FROM      B b
WHERE     b.id = a.id
AND       b.modified_date > a.modified.date
ORDER BY  b.modified_date
```

Hope this helps!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can try using a `CASE` expression on SQL Server

```
SELECT A.id,A.other_columns, 
(CASE WHEN a.modified_date > b.modified_date THEN a.modified_date ELSE b.modified_date END) as modified_date 
FROM [A] INNER JOIN [B] on A.id=B.id
```